Google tag manager is firing all scroll depth together on 2nd page
I have setup a 25, 50, 70 and 90 percent scroll depth on my website, I have infinite scroll activated on the posts. When my website scrolls 1st page, the scroll depts are counted properly. But as the page goes to 2nd post, all 4 scroll depths are counted together. Is there any way we can solve it?
Is there any change in Google tag manager I have to specify in conditions?

Modify the scroll depth triggers:
Make sure that the scroll depth triggers are configured to trigger only once per page view. In GTM, go to "Triggers" and check the settings of your scroll depth triggers.
Use the "Page Path" variable to differentiate between different pages or articles. This can help ensure that the triggers reset correctly when a new page is loaded via infinite scroll.
